¿Cómo visualizar diagramas con relaciones desde archivos exportados (pg_dump, dbschema) o conectandose a la base de datos en herramientas de modelado?
e estado investigando varias herramientas de modelado de bases de datos y necesito visualizar diagramas con sus relaciones, ya sea importando archivos generados por pg_dump de PostgreSQL y dbschema de Informix, o en ultima instancia mediante la conexión directa a las bases de datos.
He investigado las siguientes herramientas:

Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler
Visual Paradigm
Toad Data Modeler
ER/Studio Data Architect
DBVisualizer
Enterprise Architect
Talend Data Integration

Mi objetivo es visualizar los diagramas de las bases de datos, incluyendo las relaciones entre tablas (llaves foráneas y primarias). Sin embargo, he encontrado que no todas las herramientas reconocen automáticamente las relaciones entre tablas, no dejan importar los archivos generados, entre otras cosas (Informix es el mas problemático).
Mis preguntas son:
¿Alguna de estas herramientas soporta correctamente la importación de archivos de pg_dump o dbschema con las relaciones entre tablas incluidas?
¿Hay alguna otra herramienta que recomienden que pueda servir para este caso?
Debido a problemas externos en donde trabajo no puedo probarlas directamente al menos hasta estar seguro de que funcionan para el propósito que describí.
Cualquier experiencia o consejo con estas herramientas será de gran ayuda. ¡Gracias de antemano!

La herramienta dbevaer es free y te permite obtener el diagrama de con sus relaciones, al menos para PostgreSQL funciona bien

Hola, muchas gracias, probé ese programa junto a dbvisualizer y funcionaron bien, gracias por la respuesta.
